# Is asp.net mvc suitable for this application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The application consists of lots of **runtime** generated grids and charts.
Coloring of gridcells will be required for some threshold based on data. 
also there will be use of ajax for sorting, paging and exporting on gridviews.

Should I go with webforms or can mvc provide some benefits over webforms when struggling with
preinits, event bindings and viewstate for runtime grid and chart generation.

Pre-thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing that you described that ASP.NET MVC wouldn't be able to handle and then some.

Having said that, you should consider a few things.

1. The webforms page life cycle that you're describing is not used in ASP.NET MVC.
2. There is no viewstate, there is a concept of a model that you use, but viewstate is gone.
3. If you're using third party controls for your grids and charts you need to make sure they are compatible with ASP.NET MVC.  They may not be, especially if they utilize viewstate.
4. You don't get charts and grids out of the box with MVC, you have to implement the syntax yourself, or buy some controls that do.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things about ASP.NET MVC that folks don't seem to mention too often is that for many things, more work and development time is required over a standard ASP.NET application.

ASP.NET MVC gives you a lot of *control* over your application but that means you forgo a lot of the RAD conveniences that standard ASP.NET offers.